# Как выбрать одну ссылку в навигации для стилизации?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Есть такая проблема: есть навигация, пункты меню и ссылки в них, хочу выбрать первую ссылку для стилизации, испробовал - `first-child` и `nth-child(1)` - ничего не работает.
Подскажите, как это можно справить, хочу применить `border-radius` для первой ссылки.

Мой код:

```css
.menu__link {
     display: block;
     padding: 10px 40px;
     color: #fff;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     letter-spacing: 2px;
     text-shadow: 4px 4px 5px black;
     transition: background .25s;
     background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
}
.menu__link:hover{
     background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}
    
.menu__link:nth-child(1){
     border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
    
.menu__link:nth-child(6){
     border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
 <menu class="menu">
   <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Секция 1</a></li>
   <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Секция 2</a></li>
   <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Секция 3</a></li>
   <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Секция 4</a></li>
   <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Секция 5</a></li>
   <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Секция 6</a></li>
 </menu>
</nav>
```

Comment: Покажи `css`, как ты пытался...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В таком виде все работает.
Чтобы был виден результат border-radius, нужно задать border.

```css
.menu__item:first-child .menu__link {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <menu class="menu">
    <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Секция 1</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Секция 2</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Секция 3</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Секция 4</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Секция 5</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Секция 6</a></li>
  </menu>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

`:first-child` нужно применять для элемента списка `li`, а не для `a`

```
.menu > .menu__item:first-child > .menu__link {
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```